# JSON response for a nested SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I have the structure like below I am currently looking to get a JSON response like this with a SPARQL query I have tried few things like concat and str but dint work out that well for me it got complicated at 3rd level

I have now added 2 frames that I have tried with JSON-LD Framing it gives the correct output until the first level at second level it fails to expand the data

````
:Reference xx1:timestamp  "12/15/2020" .
:Reference xx2:logs xxx:log1 .


:log1   rdf:type        xxx:Logs .
:log1   xx1:approver  "xxx:bob" .
:log1   xx1:requester "xxx:daisy" .
:log1   xx1:timestamp  "12/15/2020" .
:log1   xx1:name   "log1" .

:log2   rdf:type        xxx:Logs .
:log2   xx1:approver   "xxx:bob" .
:log2   xx1:requester  "xxx.daisy" .
:log2   xx1:timestamp  "18/15/2020" .
:log2   xx1:name   "log2" .

:bob   rdf:type        xxx:User .
:bob   xx1:name   "bob" .

:daisy   rdf:type        xxx:User .
:daisy   xx1:name   "daisy" .```

Required Response with SPARQL (3 Levels)
[
  {
    "timestamp": "12/15/2020",   
    "logs": [
      { "name": "log1", "timestamp": "12/15/2020"  "approver" : {name: bob },"requester" : {name: bob }},
      { "name": "log2", "timestamp": "12/15/2020"  "approver" : {name: bob },"requester" : {name: bob }},
    ]
  }
]

    JSON-LD FRAMING
FRAME 1
{
   "@context":{
      "XXX":"http://ABC"
   },
   "@type":"xxx:Reference",
   "contains":{
      "@type":"xxx:Log",
      "contains":{
         "@type":"xxx:User"
      }
   }
}


FRAME 2

{
   "@context":{
      "XXX":"http://ABC"
   },
   "@type":"xxx:Reference",
   "contains":{
      "@type":"xxx:Log",
      "hasApprover" :{"@type":"xxx:User"},
      "hasRequester" :{"@type":"xxx:User"}
   }
}

The output that I get is 
Reference [Log 1 {User is expnded}, Log2{User is not expanded}]

What I need is 
Reference [Log 1 {User is expanded}, Log2{User is expanded}]
````

Comment: that's not possible unless the SPARQL API of your choice supports some kind of framing which is not standard

Comment: also I can't see your query, with CONSTRUCT you could at least use JSON-LD

Comment: Take a look at the non-standard extension: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/generate-json-from-sparql.html It is not a complete solution to the requirement but it may produce a form more easily converted to that JSON structure.

Comment: @AndyS I tried it with couple of triple stores like graphdb then blazegraph neptune it dint work with any I always get Bad Request

Comment: @UninformedUser I tried writing a template I have updated it above but I don't get the second level right or as intended

Comment: Ok I found the correct Frame Just had to include "@embed": "@always"

Comment: great, so can you provide it as an answer then?

Comment: @user3663894 - as noted, it's a jena extension.

Answer (score 0):

This JSON-LD frame helps to get the required result

```
   "@context":{
      "XXX":"http://ABC"
   },
   "@type":"xxx:Reference",
   "contains":{
      "@type":"xxx:Log",
      "hasApprover" :{"@type":"xxx:User","@embed": "@always"},
      "hasRequester" :{"@type":"xxx:User","@embed": "@always"}
   }
}
```